# Sockjs gives SSL protocol error on remote server but works on local

Tags: java, angular, nginx, websocket, sockjs

Hi All so I'm working on sockJS web sockets with angular as frontend and JAVA as backend everything works fine on local but I get **net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR**

[image]

Http frontend to http backend works
Https frontend to http backend doesn't work how do i get past this via nginx or any solutions??

My sockjs sits behind nginx

Below is my nginx conf file

```
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    server_name test-xyz.pcr.com;

    client_max_body_size 20M;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/xyz_cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/xyz_decrypt.key;

    gzip on;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json image/svg+xml image/x-icon font/opentype text/x-component application/x-font-ttf;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error_log warn;

    location / {
        proxy_ssl_name test-xyz.pcr.com;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
         client_max_body_size 20M;
    }

    location /api/ {
      proxy_pass http://test-xyz.pcr.com:8080/api/;
      proxy_connect_timeout       600;
      proxy_send_timeout          600;
      proxy_read_timeout          600;
      send_timeout                600;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
  }

location /socket/ {
    proxy_pass http://test-xyz.pcr.com:8080/socket/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
} 

}
```

i have tried this but still get an error

angular file

```
public  connect() {
  var socket = new SockJS("https://test-xyz.pcr.com:8080/socket");
  var stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
  stompClient.connect({},  (frame) => {
          console.log('Connected: ' + frame);   
          stompClient.subscribe('/chat', (payload) => {
         if(payload.body.indexOf('completed') > -1){
          this.uploadLoading = false
        
         this.fetchDataFromDb()
          this.snackBar.open("Data uploaded sucessfully..", "Dismiss", { duration: 4000 });
          console.log("callingDB")
         }else{
this.progressMessage = payload.body
         }
          });
      },  (error) => {  
        this.uploadLoading = false
       console.log("onError() called");
                  console.log("error: ",error);
      });
};
```

JAVA config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfiguration extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/socket")
                .setAllowedOriginPatterns("*")
                .withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app")
                .enableSimpleBroker("/chat"); // Enables a simple in-memory broker
    }
}
```

I have also tried the below fix [--public-host=0.0.0.0:0](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/19403) which also didn't work

i also get this error on backend java ,i understand its due to Https traffic from 443 coming to http 8080 port how do I by pass this nginx

[image: Error]

I am a beginner and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong any advice would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

As I am a beginner and after a lot of trail and error ,i figured out that it was not nginx issue .The issue was my 8080 port not accepting https requests since its a http port ,so i had to re configure my backend to accept https on 8443 and redirect the https socket connection to 8443 [Enable https in Spring Boot](https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-ssl/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).